# How to install only babel related devDependencies in package.json?

Tags: node.js, security, npm, babeljs, devops

the devDependencies section in my project looks like this:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-http": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.5"
  },
```

they are all dependencies for development.

But `@babel/cli`, `@babel/core`, `@babel/preset-node` are the only dev dependencies that my build machine needs to `compile` the ES6/ES7 source to dist which is for production.

My building machine is a jenkins slave, which run the building jobs in one time only, with --rm option, docker containers. To optimize the DevOps process, in this compiling job, all other deps, even the production deps are not necessary.

But according to the [npm/install doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), the best command for me is

```
npm install --only=development
```

that I think is still over killing.

If I run `npm install @babel/cli @babel/node @babel/preset-env`, they would be added to the "dependencies" section in package.json.

If I run `npm install @babel/cli @babel/node @babel/preset-env -D`, they would overwrite to the "devDependencies" section in package.json.

In these two approaches, npm would not honor the version tag in package.json or package-lock.json.

I have also considered that putting all other devDeps, like chai, mocha, to [optionalDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#optionaldependencies), but it is not what this section intended to mean, and there is no command to install optional only deps with `npm install`.

Comment: I want this feature because of the flatmap-stream issue, https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream/issues/116, one of my task failed because npm.com has remove the package on the registry. I am totally okay with that. Then i realized it requires this package because nodemon depends on it. But somehow nodemon is not required at all in this compiling task.

Comment: maybe the only simple way to do it is https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408662/230640

Answer (score 1):

OK. To be clear. Your problem is after NPM 5.8.0. When they change the `--save` option on by default.

For your problem. I think you can write a bash function something like:

```
function npm-temp-install {
    pkg=`cat package.json | jq -r ".devDependencies.$1" | sed "s/^/$1@/"`
    npm install $pkg -D
}
```

Then you can run `npm-temp-install @babel/cli` to install the package with the specific version that listed in your `devDependencies`.

For your first comment:
I think you can use `npx` to run nodemon. From its [website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx). It said it will help you download the package if the command is not found in `node_modules/.bin`. And it won't change the `package.json` or `package-lock.json`.

Comment: the dep for nodemon is missing for a reason: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/releases/tag/v1.18.7 https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3039

Answer (score 0):

remove package-lock.json and run

```
npm install @babel/cli @babel/node @babel/preset-env -D
```